# Getting structure from file in C

Tags: c

I have a problem with reading structure from file. I think it's kind of obvious, but I can't grasp it.
Here's my code:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    ungetc(c, fp);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &stud_list[i].group);
    do { c = fgetc(fp); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);

    fgets(stud_list[i].surname, 50, fp);
    stud_list[i].surname[strcspn(stud_list[i].surname, "\n")] = 0;

    fgets(stud_list[i].name, 50, fp);
    stud_list[i].name[strcspn(stud_list[i].name, "\n")] = 0;

    fgets(stud_list[i].patronymic, 50, fp);
    stud_list[i].patronymic[strcspn(stud_list[i].patronymic, "\n")] = 0;

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &stud_list[i].year);
    do { c = fgetc(fp); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    fscanf(fp, "%d ", &stud_list[i].marks[j]);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &stud_list[i].marks[4]);
    i++;
}
```

Then I printed it to another file:

```
while (stud_list[t].group) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", stud_list[t].group);

    fputs(stud_list[t].surname, fp);
    fputc('\n', fp);
    fputs(stud_list[t].name, fp);
    fputc('\n', fp);
    fputs(stud_list[t].patronymic, fp);
    fputc('\n', fp);

    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", stud_list[t].year);
    for (j=0;j<4;j++)
    fprintf(fp, "%d ", stud_list[t].marks[j]);
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", stud_list[t].marks[4]);
    t++;
}
```

What I expected to get:

```
11
Иванов
Иван
Иванович
1990
5 5 5 5 5
12
Маяковский
Владимир
Владимирович
1893
5 5 5 5 4
```

What I got:

11
Иванов
Иван
Иванович
1990
5 5 5 5 12
12
Маяковский
Владимир
Владимирович
1893
5 5 5 5 4
4
0
0 0 0 0 0

I hope you'll find a mistake. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What *did* you get? And how is that file encoded? It's definitely not ASCII.

Comment: "it prints incorrect", should we take this to mean that the output file contains the text "incorrect"? If not, can you *please* tell us what you *did* get?

Comment: It's windows-1251. it prints the same structure and excessive zeros below.

Comment: Red http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Always a bug: not testing the return value from fscanf(). You simply assume input is correctly formed. It might not be.

Comment: @Sherstnyov Where are the header files? :o